# How to invoke exe file through Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We have one windows application installed in Azure VM. We want to execute that application using Azure so that we will be able to monitor execution of this application using Azure portal.

Is there any way to invoke an executable present in one Azure VM using Azure Data Factory pipeline or some other service present in Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does the exe do? Is it a console app?

Generally, I think it's possible.

This can be achieved by using [ADF Custom Activity](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-use-custom-activities/). You may rewrite your app as a custom activity, which will be run in Azure Batch VMs.

If your app can't be run in Azure Batch, you will have to enable something like PowerShell remoting, so that exe can be launched remotely. Caveat is, even in this case, you will still need a Custom Activity / Azure Batch as invoker, since ADF Pipeline itself can't do remote call or run custom code.

Hope this will help.